# How to add a new target in binutils?

Tags: porting, binutils

I want to add a new targets in binutils version 2.23.

Please tell me the list of files that require modification.

I really hope someone can give me some advice, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this.

https://sourceware.org/binutils/binutils-porting-guide.txt

This is a guide text.

You also check porting project in GitHub. (Search "port binutils" in GitHub)